# Insert date ranges for each Row with from-to dates, Add a fixed value to rows as per date change & Payment recieved adjusting to fixed value

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using `VB.NET` and `SQL Server 2012`.

I have a `SQL` Database named **`DB_COLLECTOR`**, 
as well as a table named **`Fee_Payment`**, 
with 6 columns named:

```
'S_No' Int Primary key identity(1,1),
'Date_Start' datetime Null,
'Date_End' datetime Null,
'Prefixed_Fee' decimal(10) Null, 
'Paid_Amount' decimal(10) Null, 
'Balance' decimal(10) Null
```

---

I also have **2 Forms**:

The 1st Form takes `Person Name, Deal_Start_Date, Deal_End_Date, Monthly_Fee` and saves it into a **`Customer_Master`** table in the database.

And, another form, which takes `Person Name, Payment_Amount` and saves that  'Fee_Payment' table.

---

#### The problem:

If I enter a `Deal_Start_Date` of `01/04/2018` and a `Deal_End_Date` of `31/03/2019`, for a customer named "John" who has a monthly fee of $50.00 on the 1st Form, there are three things that **should** happen:

1. It **should automatically** add 12 Rows into the `Fee_Payment` table with each row having the `Date_Start` as `01-Apr-2018`, and `Date_End` as `30-Apr-2018`, apart from the relevant data saved to `Customer_Master`. Like this:

   ```
   S_No  Date_Start  Date_End      Prefixed_Fee   Paid_Amount  Balance  
   ----  ----------  --------      ------------   -----------  -------  
   1     01-Apr-2018 30-Apr-2018      Null           Null       Null    
   2     01-May-2018 31-May-2018      Null           Null       Null    
   3     01-Jun-2018 30-Jun-2018      Null           Null       Null    
   ..     ....         ....            ..             ..         ..     
   12    01-Mar-2019 31-Mar-2019      Null           Null       Null
   ```
2. It **should**, also, **automatically** replace `Null` with `$50.00` in the `Prefixed_Fee` Column of the `Apr-2018` row (the top one) if the date has come under the range of `01-Apr-2018` to `30-Apr-2018` i.e. if the current date is `02-Apr-2018`. Like this:

   ```
   S_No  Date_Start  Date_End      Prefixed_Fee   Paid_Amount  Balance  
   ----  ----------  --------      ------------   -----------  -------  
   1     01-Apr-2018 30-Apr-2018      50.00          Null       50.00   
   2     01-May-2018 31-May-2018      Null           Null       Null    
   3     01-Jun-2018 30-Jun-2018      Null           Null       Null    
   ..     ....         ....            ..             ..         ..     
   12    01-Mar-2019 31-Mar-2019      Null           Null       Null
   ```
3. So, if the customer, John, had paid `$125.00`, it should allocate `$50.00` (from `$125.00`) to the first row, by filling the amount mentioned in `Prefixed_Fee` and ***then*** from the `Balance`, put `$50.00` into second row and, finally, the `Balance` amount of `$25.00` to the third row.

   ```
   S_No  Date_Start  Date_End      Prefixed_Fee   Paid_Amount  Balance  
   ----  ----------  --------      ------------   -----------  -------  
   1     01-Apr-2018 30-Apr-2018      50.00          50.00      0.00    
   2     01-May-2018 31-May-2018      50.00          50.00      0.00    
   3     01-Jun-2018 30-Jun-2018      50.00          25.00      25.00   
   ..     ....         ....            ..             ..         ..     
   12    01-Mar-2019 31-Mar-2019      Null           Null       Null
   ```

How do I do this?

Comment: So, what is your question here (we just have a list of requirements, and we're not here to do your work for you)? What have you tried? This *looks* like a homework question.

Comment: The last view of your table should show for the second record 0 in the prefixed_fee column, 50.00 in the paid column and (50.00) in the last column. The service has not yet been provided so a credit balance should be shown. How is this table connected to the customer table? Show what you have tried and tell us how it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry! Not a homework. I dont think this is so easy as a Homework to solve, else I would never be here to trouble anybody.

Comment: Respected Seniors! Actually, 1st help required is that when 2 known dates are given, it should add each row for each month  Till the count of Months between the 2 dates. (I have less idea about date functions). Now, in each row, it should also give the start & end date of each month in its row automatically.   (During a Customer deal creation, user gives NAME, Deal START & END Dates, Each Monthly deal AMOUNT. When SUBMIT button is clicked & Sql table lists the said Rows as said). By this 1st Process ends.

Comment: 2nd help is required that assume that we created the deal, now, the System (VB.net  or SQL) should automatically check whether the system date comes in the range of a month to say if deal start date is 01-Apr-2018 & End date is 31-Dec-2018, then if the system date passes 01-Apr-2018 it should add to the prefix column amount as $50.00. Likewise for everymonth automatically, till the End date i.e. 31-Dec-2018

Comment: By the above action, 2nd Process ends. Now, the 3rd help required is that when later, the Customer makes a payment that would be any amount of bulk payment is done i.e.  to say if given 2.5 month fee, that amount should adjust by filling Prefixed fee of $50 to Apr, then $50 to May & $25 to Jun, whereas the balance column should show $25 as balance after deducting the allocated $25 to Jun. By this, 3rd process ends.

Comment: Thanks to Larnu & Mary! Atleast you people responded... Larnu, 1 question, but 3 parts.

Comment: Mary, Customer_Master Table takes only the Start & End of deal dates during Customer deal Creation. But at the same time of creation, (the count of month between both dates) * Rows are created with Start & End Dates of Each month in each of its row thereby assigning that dates to Date_Start & Date_End respectively.

Comment: @Md_Ms,why don't we [Continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168058/beginners)